# When to use W3C's xmlns and xmlns:xsi namespaces?

Tags: xml, namespaces, xsd

I have a rather fundamental question about XML here.  When declaring an element's `xmlns` attribute, is it ever legal to use `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`?  And when declaring the `xmlns:xsi` attribute, is it legal to use `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` as the value?

I ask this because I have seen XML auto-generated by some XML editors which references these namespaces, and yet (at least on the `XMLSchema-instance` page) W3C says that "This schema should never be used as such: [the XML Schema Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#no-xsi) forbids the declaration of attributes in this namespace".

So I'm confused; is it always illegal to say something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myElement xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    [...]
</myElement>
```

... and if not, why does W3C seem to say that the namespace should never be used?  What would one use it for?  I've tried to read the XML 1.0 spec but it's extremely verbose and difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That namespace should not be used for anything else. It must be used to reference the attributes declared within that namespace.

You may not declare any elements or attributes within a namespace that belongs to someone else. This means you may not declare your `myElement` within the "XMLSchema" namespace.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<root xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <genericElement xsi:type="xs:string">string</genericElement>
</root>
```

Comment: I'm still not quite sure, then, on why the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` namespace is needed at all.  It defines the schema which allows one to define another XML schema, right?  Could you expand your answer to give an example of where `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` could legally and appropriately be used, and where `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` could legally and appropriately be used?